# How to display Draft.js data including hyperlinks?

Tags: hyperlink, draftjs

Creating an editor using draft.js. Facing problem while displaying it when it includes link tags. without link tag, its working fine. I followed  [this](https://codepulse.blog/simple-easy-way-display-draft-js-content/) blog to implement the fetching funtionality.

Saving data in local storage for testing.

```
localStorage.setItem("testObject", JSON.stringify(editorData));
```

then feting it like this:

```
render() {
    const contentState = convertFromRaw(localStorage.testObject);
    const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
    return (
         <div className="App">
             <Editor editorState={editorState} readOnly={true} />
         </div>
    );
```

bold and italic styling are displaying correctly but links aren't. For link example click [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to let Draft.js completely manage your links - you have to insert links via Draft API as well.

To insert links - use RichUtils.toggleLink() API, you can find an example [here](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/main/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html).

To display links,  create your own decorator that builds a link element, and register this decorator with draft.js:

```
 const Link = (props) => {
  const {url} = Entity.get(props.entityKey).getData();
  return (
    <a href={url}>{props.children}</a>
  )
}

function findLinkEntities(contentBlock, callback) {
  contentBlock.findEntityRanges(
    (character) => {
      const entityKey = character.getEntity();
      return (
        entityKey !== null &&
        Entity.get(entityKey).getType() === 'LINK'
      )
    },
    callback
  )
}

const decorators = [
  { strategy: findLinkEntities, component: Link }
]


const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(state, new CompositeDecorator(decorators))


<Editor decorators={decorators} 
        editorState={editorState}
    ... />
```